# ZFS + GlusterFS + NFS stack returning wrong file to client (weird behaviour)

Tags: nfs, zfs, glusterfs

I set up an NFS server on top of a replicated GlusterFS volume on top of mirrored ZFS pool serving files to a couple of application servers.

[ZFS + GlusterFS + NFS cluster schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riMRZ.png)

I have two application servers retrieving files stored on an NFS share. Workload is almost *write once/read sometimes*: files are written to storage and almost never modified; sometimes they are read to serve a request.

Before returning the data to the requesting client, the application calculates the file SHA256 hash and compares it with the one stored in its database.

Even if the application is using the full path to the file, sometime one node get completely different (and wrong) file contents, eg.: the application asks for file `/data/storage_archive/20220802/filename` and gets data from file `/data/storage_archive/RANDOM_DATE_HERE/RANDOM_FILENAME`.

When this happens (luckily only a couple of times as of now), logging on the application server, I can copy the (wrong) file from the (right) path to local storage for further analysis and the file content is still wrong. Excluding the filename, other metadata like file size, file creation date, etc. are correct and reflects the real (wrong) file.

With *wrong* I mean a complete and intact file (no bitrot or other corruption), e.g.: an intact XML file instead of a PDF one.

If I try to access the same file from the other application server mounting the same NFS share, I get the correct file.

Moving down through the various layers I did:

- check SHA256 of the file on both the GlusterFS nodes; the hash is correct
- check SHA256 of the file on the ZFS dataset mountpoint; the hash is correct

Unmounting and remounting the NFS share on the client side brings the situation back to normality.

I suppose I hit some cache corruption somewhere in the chain but I cannot understand where: NFS? GlusterFS? ZFS?
Thinking about the layers involved, ZFS looks the culprit because it is the first actor that could reply with wrong data but at the same time it should be the almost bullet proof layer.
No intensive tasks (backups, rsync, large directory traversal, etc.) were running when I got the errors.

Below you can find some details about ZFS and GlusterFS configuration

```
 pool: testdata
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 19h4m with 0 errors on Sun Jul 10 19:28:54 2022
 config:

        NAME                                   STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        testdata                               ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST16000NM001G-2KK103_ZL2JSCGA  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST16000NM001G-2KK103_ZL2JS4SB  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Sample gluster volume information:

```
gluster volume info test_volume

Volume Name: test_volume
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 2ca11c4a-442f-4887-b65f-f02a34b14b03
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gluster01-10gbe:/data/testdata/test_volume/data
Brick2: gluster02-10gbe:/data/testdata/test_volume/data
Options Reconfigured:
server.event-threads: 2
performance.parallel-readdir: on
performance.readdir-ahead: off
network.inode-lru-limit: 50000
performance.client-io-threads: off
nfs.disable: on
transport.address-family: inet
storage.fips-mode-rchecksum: on
cluster.granular-entry-heal: on
cluster.enable-shared-storage: enable
```

GlusterFS mount on cluster:

```
gluster01-10gbe:/test_volume /mnt/testdata/test_volume/data/ glusterfs defaults 0 0
```

NFS exports on cluster:

```
/mnt/testdata/test_volume/data/    10.1.1.2(rw,fsid=1,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash) 10.1.1.3(rw,fsid=1,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

NFS mount on application server:

```
10.1.1.1:/mnt/testdata/test_volume/data/        /data  nfs     proto=udp,nfsvers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,soft  0   0
```

*IP addresses, volume names, pool names, etc, have been replaced to avoid the risk of sensitive information disclosure*

Some details about storage servers:

- HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 equipped with:
- Dual Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2450L @ 1.80GHz
- 64GB RAM
- Dell Perc H200 (IT Mode)
- 10GbE network
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- OpenZFS on Linux 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.12